# Installation problems with cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have installed the latest version of node.js from the official nodejs.org website but when i run the install command in my cmd of windows 
npm install -g cordova

It installs with the following warnings.

```
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.9.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
C:\Users\Gaurav\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\Gaurav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@5.0.0 C:\Users\Gaurav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@5.0.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semve
r@2.1.0, rc@0.5.2, shelljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, d8@0.4.4, init-package-json@1.4.2, elemen
ttree@0.1.5, request@2.47.0, tar@1.0.2, glob@4.0.6, cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.2, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js
@3.9.0, npm@1.3.4)
```

Comment: The warnings would be more useful as text anyway, you should be able to copy and paste them here from your terminal / console / shell.

Comment: Do you try to follow official instructions? (http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a version of node higher than what is wanted.

cordova requires `0.10.0` and you have `0.12.2`.

I suggest you use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to easily installing different versions.

First install `nvm` using this command.

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.0/install.sh | bash`

Then you can a specific version with `nvm install 0.10`.

---

Here are your errors formatted.

```
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.9.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
```

Comment: Thanks Edward but i doubt the above command will run in cmd , bearing in mind that i am using windows cmd

Comment: If you read the docs it says windows versions are available https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Answer (score 0):

These are just warnings saying that the required minimal versions of node.js is different from your version of nodejs (v0.12.2).

This shouldn't be a problem for you

Comment: Hmmmh, the warning says that Cordova expects the nodejs version to be 0.10.xxx. NO word about "higher than ..."
So how do you come to the statement  "This shouldn't be a problem for you" ???
Seems that the Cordova maintainers don't catch up with the newer versions of nodes, npm , ... ??? On their pages (at least) I can't find any statement related to the 0.12 version